# How to make decimal converter in pep\9

Tags: pep9-assembly

I don't know how to make decimal converter in pep/9

The rule is

Enter a decimal number to be converted

166

Enter a new base

16

The answer is

A6
using this form
I can make decimal computer in c
But i have no idea what to do in pep\9
anyone please help me how to make decimal converter in pep\9